# Creating Multiple Objects with the Same Uploaded File in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an attachment for a ticket and this attachment should be able to created for multiple customers. But when you get the uploaded file and create an object with it, Django automatically close the file. So, it gives `I/O operation on closed file` error and I can't create another object with that file. Is there any way of doing this?

`models.py`

```py
class Customer(models.Model):  
  name = models.CharField(max_length=123)

class Ticket(models.Model):
  ticket_name = models.CharField(max_length=123)
  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name="c", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  

class Attachment(models.Model):  
  file_name = models.CharField(max_length=123)  
  content = models.FileField(upload_to=/somewhere)  
  ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, related_name="ticket_attachment", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

`views.py`

```py
from models import Customer, Ticket, Attachment  

class MyView(generic.FormView):
  def form_valid(self, form):  
    myFile = self.request.FILES.get('attachment')
    for customer in form.cleaned_data["customer"]:
      ticket = Ticket.objects.create(ticket_name=form.cleaned_data.get("ticket_name"),customer=customer)
      Attachment.objects.create(file_name=myFile._name, content=myFile, ticket=ticket)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Ok try to put you self.request.FILES.get('attachment') inside a dict like this myFile['attach_file']  = self.request.FILES.get('attachment') and now dont use create try to use something like this Attachment(file_name=File._name, content=myFile['attach_file'], ticket=ticket) and finaly Attachment.save()

Comment: It didn't work. I had also tried a similar approach by creating a list of objects and save them after finishing the function but it doesn't work. Because this time, when you do the first save it closes the file again. @NathanIngram